# How to get cell data value of Datagrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, datagridcell

I am very much new to WPF and I want to make an data entry form with `Datagrid` control. I am stuck with , how to get cell data value to store them into database?

Like in windows, we used to get it through `gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0].value`.

how to get this in WPF?

Answer (score -1):

You Can obtain using the following code.

```
public void DataGridCellValue(object param)
    {
        string clipboard = string.Empty;
        if (param != null)
        {

            if (param is DataGridCell)
            {
                DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)param;
                dynamic column = cell.Column as DataGridTextColumn;

                if (cell.Column is DataGridTextColumn)
                    column = cell.Column as DataGridTextColumn;

                if (cell.Content is TextBlock)
                {
                    TextBlock tBlock = cell.Content as TextBlock;
                    clipboard = string.IsNullOrEmpty(tBlock.Text) ? string.Empty : tBlock.Text.Trim();
                }
            }
            else if (param.GetType().IsValueType)
            {
                clipboard = param.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public ICommand DataGridCellValue
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegatingCommand((object param) =>
            {
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    DataGridCopyToClipBoard(param);
                }).Invoke();
            });
        }
    }
```

Use the Binding as like this in your WPF XAML

```
"{Binding CurrentCell, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

The Command and CommandParameter's are

```
Command="{Binding DataGridCellValue}"
CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentCell, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to WPF then go through these two links below to start and understand how it is done in WPF:

1. [Binding in WPF](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/)
2. [DataGrid Data Binaing](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)

> **As a brief**, you really never has to do
>   `gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[0].value` in WPF, instead you can bind your
>   grid to a data source. and then try to get the values from datasource
>   collection.(if you are not looking UI specific like : cell 0 of row 0 etc. )

Comment: I wanted a blank Datagrid for the user to input data and then Save it in Database. For that I bound the empty Datatable to the Datagrid and left few textboxes for User input and 1 button which will add textbox values to the grid. and for Saving, i assigned the datagrid's datacontext to Datatable and did the further work out on Datatable itself which sved data to the database. Now please tell me..is it a good practice for WPF???? I doubt it is.

Comment: @AeshaPatel though you have given this description , i have many questions like why user enter values in text box, and then you use a button's event to fill the grid with those values. can't you just user enter text in grid itself. Also you don't need to assign anything back to datatable, just bind your data table as grid'e itemsource and any new data in grid will be reflected back to your datatable, no explicit code is required for this in WPF. I'll be able to tell you better if you give me some code also.